# Display activity indicator on api call Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I want to display an activity indicator when api call is performed. The activity indicator should stop when the api response is received

But Activity indicator is not displaying during the api call am new to swift here is my code.

```
import UIKit

var ARR_states : NSArray = NSArray()
var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var VW_overlay: UIView = UIView()

class VC_search_Course: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var TBL_states :UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    VW_overlay = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    VW_overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)

    activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
    activityIndicatorView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: activityIndicatorView.bounds.size.width, height: activityIndicatorView.bounds.size.height)

    activityIndicatorView.center = VW_overlay.center
    VW_overlay.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    VW_overlay.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(VW_overlay)

    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    perform(#selector(self.Places_API), with: activityIndicatorView, afterDelay: 0.01)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}



@IBAction func button_back(sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func Places_API()
{
    let STR_url = String(format: "%@/search_by_location", SERVER_URL)
    let auth_tok = String(format:"%@",UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"auth_token") as! CVarArg)
       if let url = NSURL(string:STR_url) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue(auth_tok, forHTTPHeaderField: "auth_token")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            let temp_dictin: [AnyHashable: Any]? = ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [AnyHashable: Any])


            ARR_states = temp_dictin?["course_locations"] as! NSArray
            NSLog("States response %@", ARR_states)

        }
        task.resume()
    }

    activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    VW_overlay.isHidden = true
}
}
```

This above code is not displaying activity indicator I tried changing the view background colour. and activity indicator colour but no use

Comment: So where is the problem? Here you just have the code for start animating. Once you get eh response, just call stopAnimating

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: will have to elaborate a bit more here

Comment: when I try to call api the VW_overlay & activityIndicatorView is not displayed in the screen @mding5692

Comment: with out activityIndicatorView your VW_overlay is displayed or not

Comment: Yeah VW_overlay is also not displaying @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Please make sure that you'r VW_overlay is on top of all the view. Try `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: VW_overlay)`

Comment: @AJSanjay - where you called this code `VW_overlay = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)........` in viewdidload or else as well as where you hide your VW_overlay is initialy

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        VW_overlay = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        VW_overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        
        activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)

Comment: call your method in viewdidappear and check once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have edited the question now I posted the entire swift file

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you please confirm activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    VW_overlay.isHidden = true are in right places on func Places_API()

Comment: hide this two lines `activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    VW_overlay.isHidden = true` and check once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150567/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-aj-sanjay).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yeah now VW_overlay and activityIndicatorView is displayed but how to stop it when I receive api response

Comment: @AJSanjay, it's simple: You're calling `activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()` immediately. Instead, call it in the callback handler once the request has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove your code from

```
task.resume()
}

// activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
// VW_overlay.isHidden = true
```

and add into inside the block call your code in the following place

```
 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

       // call here 
       activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        VW_overlay.isHidden = true


        if error != nil {
            print("\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
       ......
```

Comment: why. VW_overlay.removeFromSuperview() if I need to call another api I have to add VW_overlay again right .. ?

Comment: Activity is stopped after 5 - 10 seconds of receiving Json data

Comment: any solution to stop immediately when I receive the response will be fine

Comment: call the stopAnimating in main_sync,

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0**

For That what i just implement two function as below. Hope this also will help you.

```
 func showLoader(view: UIView) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {

        //Customize as per your need
        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height:40))
        spinner.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        spinner.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        spinner.clipsToBounds = true
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white;
        spinner.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(spinner)
        spinner.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        return spinner
    }
```

And, For hide Activity Indicator

```
extension UIActivityIndicatorView {  
     func dismissLoader() {
            self.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        } 
 }
```

And, the `UIViewController` where you used Indicator as below.

```
    //Show
    let spinner = showLoader(view: self.view)

    //Hide
    spinner.dismissLoader()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your response handler stop the activity indicator.

```
func Places_API() {
activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
//Handle response here
}
```

Comment: No my problem is the activity indicator is not displayed

Comment: Are you sure that you are showing it on main thread and adding VW_overlay is done before you try to show activity indicator?

Answer (score 0):

Add your loader class

```
struct CircleLoader<Content>: View where Content: View {

// MARK:- variables
let circleTrackGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color.circleTrackStart, Color.circleTrackEnd]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .bottomLeading)
let circleRoundGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color.circleRoundStart, Color.circleRoundEnd]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .trailing)

let trackerRotation: Double = 2
let animationDuration: Double = 0.75

@State var isAnimating: Bool = false
@State var circleStart: CGFloat = 0.17
@State var circleEnd: CGFloat = 0.325

@State var rotationDegree: Angle = Angle.degrees(0)

@Binding var isShowing: Bool
var content: () -> Content

// MARK:- views
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
        
        self.content()
            .disabled(self.isShowing)
            .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 3 : 0)
        
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 15))
                .fill(circleTrackGradient)
            Circle()
                .trim(from: circleStart, to: circleEnd)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12, lineCap: .round))
                .fill(circleRoundGradient)
                .rotationEffect(self.rotationDegree)
        }
        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
        .onAppear() {
            if isShowing {
                self.animateLoader()
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: self.trackerRotation * self.animationDuration + (self.animationDuration), repeats: true) { (mainTimer) in
                    self.animateLoader()
                }
            }
        }
        .isHidden(!isShowing)
    }
}

// MARK:- functions
func getRotationAngle() -> Angle {
    return .degrees(360 * self.trackerRotation) + .degrees(120)
}

func animateLoader() {
    withAnimation(Animation.spring(response: animationDuration * 2 )) {
        self.rotationDegree = .degrees(-57.5)
    }
    
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: animationDuration, repeats: false) { _ in
        withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: self.trackerRotation * self.animationDuration)) {
            self.rotationDegree += self.getRotationAngle()
        }
    }
    
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: animationDuration * 1.25, repeats: false) { _ in
        withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: (self.trackerRotation * self.animationDuration) / 2.25 )) {
            self.circleEnd = 0.925
        }
    }
    
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: trackerRotation * animationDuration, repeats: false) { _ in
        self.rotationDegree = .degrees(47.5)
        withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: self.animationDuration)) {
            self.circleEnd = 0.325
        }
    }
}
}

struct CircleLoader_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    CircleLoader(isShowing: .constant(true)) {
        NavigationView {
            List(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], id: \.self) { row in
                Text(row)
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Loader Test"), displayMode: .large)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct LoginView: View {

@StateObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
@State private var loyaltyNumber = ""
@Binding var flowView: StartFlow

var body: some View {
    CircleLoader(isShowing: $viewModel.isLoading) {
        //Your API Calling from ViewModel
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]